# calling function 2 times in android. Not able to prevent clashing of 3 webservices

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver

I am working with GCM but I am facing one problem that is when I got a notification I register my `BroadcastReceiver` from my `onResume()` but sometimes my `onResume()` function is calling 2 times because of this I am facing problem. I am not understanding why this is working 2 times.

Code for gcm intent service class:

```
   if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {

            sendNotification(this, msgg);


        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {

            sendNotification(this, msgg);
            updateMyActivity(this, msgg);
            bundle.putString("result", msgg);
            receiver.send(STATUS_FINISHED, bundle);

        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            updateMyActivity(this,msgg);
            sendNotification(this, msgg);



        }
    }
//    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

}



      //This function will create an intent. This intent must take as parameter the "unique_name" that you registered your activity with
static void updateMyActivity(Context context, String message) {


    Log.e(TAG, "updateMyActivity: " );

    Intent intent = new Intent("unique_name");

    //put whatever data you want to send, if any
    intent.putExtra("message", message);

    //send broadcast
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

`onResume()` method of activity:

```
       @Override
         public void onStart()
          {
            super.onStart();
              onResume();
          }


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
            "unique_name");

    mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //extract our message from intent
            String msg_for_me = intent.getStringExtra("message");

  }
```

but I am having this  "msg_for_me " 2 times. check screenshot. http://prntscr.com/dpzxrs

Comment: Why do you call onResume in onStart?

Comment: becuase if I am  not calling it  then my resume fucntion not work for all the time work only for a time @2ndGAB

Comment: What do you mean by 'not work' it doesn't do the job or it's not called. Other thing, Is it a copy/paste mistake or your broadcast receiver is in onResume()?? You should better put it in onCreate() followed by registerReceiver() call and unRegisterReceiver() in on Destroy()

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several mistakes in your code.

First don't put you `BroadcastReceiver` in `onResume()`, don't create the `intent` as it's passed by the message and register the `BroadcastReceiver`.

In you `MainActivity`, you would better do like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { // or any other Activity like

    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.v(Constants.APP_TAG, "MainActivity: onCreate");

        mMessageReceiver  = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Log.v(Constants.APP_TAG, "MainActivity: mMessageReceiver ");

                String msg_for_me = intent.getStringExtra("message");

            }
        };

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver ,
                new IntentFilter(Constants.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        Log.v(Constants.APP_TAG, "MainActivity: onDestroy");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    }
}
```